# Getting System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied on Azure-Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, winappdriver, appium-desktop, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am running UI-Automation Test with Appium WinAppDriver using a `.bat` file. When I run the `.bat` file manually on the agent everything goes as expected but it produces
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): Access is denied exception when running through Azure Release.

Tried:
`BuildUser` is the account having admin privileges on my agent machine `DOTNET4`.
I have tried running the release pipeline using both `BuildUser` account and also my local account.

Tried different ways to run the `.bat` file as admin too.

I provided Full Control of folder in which I have `WinAppDriver.exe`, `AzureAgent.exe`, & Folder having AUT.

Azure Agent Service in running using the `BuildUser` account in Windows Services. I have this `.exe` running using `Run as Administrator`.

[image]

Contents of .bat file is attached:

```
@echo off
set TESTDIR=%~1
set LaunchedFromWinAppDriver=True
set ApplicationExe=C:\Git\filePathToExe\application.exe
C:\Git\filePathToExe\AppExeCommandLineRunner.exe -X "%ApplicationExe%"::"%TESTDIR%"
```

Code Snippet that is causing Exception:

```
public static void KillApplication()
        {
            try
            {
                string windowHandle = WindowDriver.CurrentWindowHandle;
                Log.Debug("CurrentWindowHandl:"+windowHandle);
                [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);
                IntPtr windowHandlePtr = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt64(windowHandle, 16));
                Log.Debug("WindowHandlePtr:" +windowHandlePtr.ToString());
                uint processId;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandlePtr, out processId);
                Log.Debug("Process Id for killing is: " + (int)processId);
                Process process = Process.GetProcessById((int)processId);
                process.Kill();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("FailedToKill:", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Function `GetWindowThreadProcessId` returns 0 when run using Azure Release pipeline and then process.Kill generates the exception.process. Additionally if I give a valid Process id using some other logic it fails to Kill that as well giving same access id denied.

`GetWindowThreadProcessId` returns a valid process id on which AUT is attached when the `.bat` file is run manually on the agent.

I believe this issue is due to a permission issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was happening because the Azure Agent Listener was running `as a service`. It solved when I run the `Agent.Listener.exe` manually on the system in a interactive desktop session.

Path to Listener.exe: `"C:\agent\bin\Agent.Listener.exe"`